# string turning into null when passed to another action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, .net-4.0

I am passing `search` string from `Search` action to `detail` action but on being received in `detail` action it turns out to be `null`.

I am using MVC3 and .NET framework 4.0:

```
public ActionResult Search(string search)   
{
     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
         return RedirectToAction("Index");

     return RedirectToAction("Details", "Invoice", search = search.Trim());
}


public ActionResult Details(string id)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))    
        return RedirectToAction("Index");

    ObjectParameter[] parameters = new ObjectParameter[3];

    parameters[0]= new ObjectParameter("CUSTNMBR", id);
    parameters[1] = new ObjectParameter("StartDate", System.DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-90));
    parameters[2] = new ObjectParameter("EndDate", System.DateTime.Now.Date);

    return View(_db.ExecuteFunction<Models.Invoices>("uspGetCustomerInvoices", parameters).ToList<Models.Invoices>());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MVC matches the route variables to action parameters by name, and your parameter names are inconsistent. In your redirect you assign your string to `search`. but on your Details action you are looking in a variable named `id`. You need to switch one or the other so they are using the same name.

Comment: changed the code to public ActionResult Details(string search) { if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(search)).... ..... parameters[0] = new ObjectParameter("CUSTNMBR", search); ...... }

still not working :(

Comment: Change your redirect to return RedirectToAction("Details", "Invoice", new {search = search.Trim()});